# How to find the minimum non-negative integer missing from an array of non-negative integers in most optimised way?

Tags: algorithm

A MEX (Minimum Excluded) is the minimum non-negative integer that is excluded from the collection/list.
Eg :

```
MEX [] = 0
MEX [1,2,3,4,5,10,10000] = 0
MEX [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] = 7
MEX [0,1,3,4,1000] = 2
MEX [0,2,3,4,5,6] =1
```

Given a list of non negative integers, find the MEX of the list.

So, I tried sorting the array and then comparing the number at each position with its index to find the minimum number which is missing. The time complexity of this approach is O(nlogn + n). I am looking for a more optimised solution!

Comment: Note the tag ***dsa*** is used for ***Digital Signature Algorithm*** only, not for Data Structures and Algorithms

Comment: Also is there a reason you specifically tagged two languages here, both *C++* and *Python*?

Comment: If you are already sorting the array, use something akin to binary search to find a value that is not equal to its index.   Worst case (not counting the sorting) would be something like O(log n) + O(1) values checked.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in linear time and linear space. You have to first realise that the result is bound by n.

So, create a lookup table (a bitset will do) with at most n+1 entries and then iterate over the input array. For each number < n flip the entry in your table to 1. The first value not 1 will by your result. By definition at least one bit has to be not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Without sort-:

```
lis=set([0,0,2,3,1,8,4,34,12,99,100])
for i in range(0,max(lis)+2):
    if i not in lis:
        print(i)
        break
```

Using Dictionary [Hashmap]-:

**The (amortized) time complexity is constant (O(1)) in the size of the dictionary**

```
lis=set([0,2,3,1,8,4,99,100])
dic={}
#for i in lis:
#    dic[i]=dic.get(i,0)+1  
dic=dict.fromkeys(lis, 1)  # one-liner to initialize by @_aneroid

for i in range(max(lis)+1):
    if i not in dic:
        print(i)
        break
```

**Updated Solution:-**

```
def solution(list_1):
    if not list_1:
        return 0
    #Condition for all elements present 
    # Sum of natural numbers n*(n+1)//2 -: whole number (n-1)*n//2
    n=len(list_1)-1
    if sum(list_1)==(n*(n+1))//2:
        return max(list_1)+1
    dic=dict.fromkeys(list_1, 1) 
    for num in range(max(list_1)+1):
        if num not in dic:
            return num
            break
print(solution([]))
print(solution([0,1,2,3]))
print(solution([1,2,54,32,21,46,32,0,29,88]))
print(solution(list(map(int,input().split())))) # If user want to input
```

**Output:-**

```
0
4
3
as user defined list..!
```